# Is $x^{n+1} \mod (m) = (x(x^n \mod (m))) \mod (m)$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In my compsci studies I came along an alogorithm that makes perfect sense if this is true. However, I am unable to prove it, nor am I even able to find a proof or statement saying that it is true.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's true. The more general statement is:

$$ab \bmod{m} = (a \bmod{m})(b \bmod{m}) \bmod{m}$$

To get some intuition, consider mod $10$. The last digit of $ab$ will be wholly determined by the last digit of $a$ and the last digit of $b$.

Comment: Oh, this makes it much easier.

$a = cm + d$;
$b = xm +y$;

$(ab) \mod m = (a \mod m) (b \mod m)\mod m $

$(ab) \mod m = ( ((cm +d) \mod m)) \mod m = (d* a\mod m) \mod m$

And so on.